# Eliminating Vectors to form Basis.

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I have a question with a set of vectors. Some of these are to be eliminated to obtain basis for R3.

Set of Vectors - {V1(1,0,0) V2(0,1,-1) V3(0,4,-3) V4(0,2,0)}
I have set up the equations in a 3x4 matrix and reduced them to row echelon form. This forms a linearly dependent set and I have to make this a linearly independent set to form Basis.

How to figure out which vector is linearly dependent to eliminate? I mean with more variables and less equations, we always have infinitely many solutions and a linearly dependent set but how do I figure out the exact vector which can be eliminated so this set of vectors becomes a Basis for R3.

I am starting out at mathematics, I'd really appreciate if you take the time to explicitly give me each step.
This is my first post on this website, if there are any mistakes, apologies in advance.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial.  Do you see that, if you were to eliminate $V_1$, then you wouldn't have a basis for $\mathbb R^3$, since no linear combination of $V_2, V_3$, and $V_4$ has non-zero first component?

Comment: As for a general technique, set the vectors as columns in a matrix.  Row reduce.  What results will have a pivot in each column who corresponds to an original vector who should be kept to make a basis for the space spanned by those original vectors.  Note, this process gets only one among possibly many correct answers.  Now... you say you already row reduced and you should have arrived at $\begin{bmatrix}\color{red}1&0&0&0\\0&\color{red}1&0&-6\\0&0&\color{red}1&2\end{bmatrix}$ implying your $v_1,v_2,v_3$ can act as a basis for the span of your original set of vectors.

Comment: Getting it to row-echelon form (rather than reduced row echelon form) is enough. You can then see the pivots and pick the columns from the original matrix.

Comment: @ J. W. Tanner Yes I understand to get entire /bbb R^{3} I cannot have my first variable as 0. Therefore I cannot eliminate my first vector.

Comment: @JMoravitz Can you explain how does the implication of v1, v2 and v3 acting as basis come about? I'm sorry if I am asking too basic of questions.

Comment: In the row reduced matrix, you see a pivot in the first column (*implying $v_1$ can be used in our maximally linearly independent set that we are building*), a pivot in the second column (*implying $v_2$ can also be used*) and a pivot in the third column.  The pivots are colored in red in my earlier comment.

Comment: @AmaanKhan:  If you put the components of $V_1$ and two of the other vectors in a matrix and take the determinant, it's non-zero; that means they're linearly independent

Comment: Thank you @JMoravitz